# Android: Edit child of custom Preference view in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences

So I built a custom preference view for one of the preferences in my preference activity:

```
<Preference 
      android:key="facebook_sharing"
      android:layout="@layout/fb_pref_item"/>
```

I want to be able to edit the ImageView in that custom preference layout programmatically (based on the value of the preference itself.

It would look something like this:

```
Preference facebookItem = (Preference)findPreference("facebook_sharing");
facebookItem.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

RelativeLayout rl = //get relative layout someway or another...

mFacebookIcon = (ImageView)rl.findViewById(R.id.fb_imgview);
if(!mFacebookConn.isSessionValid())
    mFacebookIcon.setColorFilter(R.color.transparent_black);
```

I can't figure out how to pull off that commented line. I've tried the following:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)facebookItem.getView(null, null); //dont know what the params ought to be...

RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(facebookItem.getLayoutResource());
```

Neither work. I searched around but can't seem to find anyone who has tried this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: providing the fb_pref_item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fb_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="68dp" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/fb_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/facebook"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/item_view_text_color" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/fb_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/fb_title" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/fb_imgview"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook64"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"  
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_icon"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You probably should provide your layout resource (`fb_pref_item.xml`), because that is what is relevant for finding the icon you're looking for.

Comment: This can work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790163/how-to-manage-custom-preference-layout. He used custom preference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided so far (see comment above, where I suggest posting the `fb_pref_item.xml` source -- you also didn't indicate if you have multiple `ImageView`s, or just one), seems to me like you're not looking for the right view.  Instead of this:

```
RelativeLayout rl = //get relative layout someway or another...
mFacebookIcon = (ImageView)rl.findViewById(R.id.fb_imgview);
```

It looks like you should be able to ignore this unnecessary `RelativeLayout` completely, and just go straight to `fb_imgview`:

```
mFacebookIcon = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.fb_imgview);
```

Note that in this case, you'd be using the inherited [`findViewById(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) method, which `PreferenceActivity` inherits directly from `Activity`, not trying to find the `RelativeLayout` first.

You can't use the `Preference#getView()` method, because that is used to **generate** the view (which will then be rendered in place in the `PreferenceActivity`).  It is not used to *obtain* the view after it is already rendered.

Comment: I gave this a go, but the ImageView and TextView end up being null values.