# Adding custom layout to PreferenceFragment

Tags: android

I have a preference fragment with a preference screen hierarchy. I would like to add a custom layout to define an "about the author" section, adding imageview to an element and a link (intent to browser). I searched but I didn't find any resources about this topic.

Comment: The `RelativeLayout` should do the job.

Comment: Ok but where i have to link the layout to the fragment? In the preference fragment class or in the xml?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your preference xml file (`res/xml/prefs.xml`), add a `Preference` with a custom layout:

```
<Preference
    android:layout="@layout/custom_preference"/>
```

Example of `layout/custom_preference.xml` with an `ImageView` and a `TextView` with a link that will be opened in the browser:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_book" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="http://www.mylink.com"
        android:autoLink="all"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It's the last preference in the screenshot:
[image: preference screen with custom preference]

Comment: I successfully add the custom layout to my preferencefragment, but how to reference the view within the preference fragment class ? i need to interact with that view to attach on click listener to the button that i add in the custom layout.

Comment: Is it possible to check custom layout text in runtime?

Comment: I guess we'll never know.

Comment: @2MuchSmoke did you figure it out?

Comment: @KaranveerSingh nope, i ended up using ordinary fragment to customize the layout.

Comment: @2MuchSmoke Ok. Although, I just did it by creating a custom Preference and accessing the layout in onBindViewHolder().

Comment: You saved my day.

Comment: How can i have a on click listener on this  and call the layout screen to pop up as a dialog ?

Answer (score 6):

This is just a follow up to the answer by Carmen (30 October 2016):

If you want to dynamically change the properties on your custom layout, after the screen has loaded, you cannot use something like this:

```
PreferenceScreen customPref = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("customPreference");
View prefRow = customPref.getView(null, null);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)prefRow.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever);
```

Although it won't crash, it will not actually do anything. It's odd and confusing.

You have to use a custom class that extends `android.preference.Preference` and override **`onBindView()`** to change properties on the custom layout. The technique is explained here: [How to manage custom preference layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790163/how-to-manage-custom-preference-layout)  [Note: For PreferenceFragmentCompat, you have to extend `androidx.preference.Preference` and override `onBindViewHolder()`]

Another way is to use `getView()` but ensure that you use `View view = super.getView(convertView, parent);`: [Android Set Custom Preference Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095643/android-set-custom-preference-layout)