# Preferences fragment as part of activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to create activity for preferences and place some Views at bottom(under preferences). I have created layout, but only first category label is visible. Why switch is invisible? Here is what i have:

- activity_layout.xml:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ScrollView
          android:id="@+id/settingsForm"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
              <fragment
                  android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  class="com.example.SettingsFragment"/>
              <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
                  <!-- views -->
              </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- SettingsFragment exends PreferenceFragment:

  ```
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
              //...
          }
  ```
- preferences.xml

  ```
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <PreferenceCategory
          android:title="@string/pref_work_storage_title"
          android:key="pref_work_category">
          <SwitchPreference
              android:key="pref_work_unavailable"
              android:defaultValue="true"
              android:summaryOn="@string/pref_work_available"
              android:summaryOff="@string/pref_work_unavailable"/>
      </PreferenceCategory>
  </PreferenceScreen>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. Preference fragment is in scrollable list itself, so to achive desired behaviour i have implemented custom preference. Here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333452/adding-custom-layout-to-preferencefragment) of custom preference layout(without preference extension).

I also have requirement to add click listeners. To implement it i have extended `Preference` class and added listeners in `onCreateView` method. Here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108609/android-creating-custom-preference) of extending preference.