# How to add image view that can be edited inside a PreferenceScreen using PreferenceFragmentCompat?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-preferences

It's seems that ImageView is not supported out of the box in PreferenceScreen, how can I implement that so it's similar to whatsapp's. 
[image]

Comment: Does this answers your question ? [Adding custom layout to PreferenceFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333452/adding-custom-layout-to-preferencefragment)

Comment: I saw that post thanks. But the image should be clickable/editable. The post doesnt provide answer for that

Comment: well you can use data-binding and viewModel and set the imageView click listener directly from the xml

Comment: Isn't there another way? That doesn't involve viewModel and databinding? That's a lot of work for just that

Comment: I'll try implementing a short sample and see if there is any other way or not for now.

Comment: I appreciate very much thanks

Comment: I have found a solution that doesn't require data-binding and viewModel. See answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, upon after some research I'm confident that following is the latest and stable solution assuming you are using [androidx.preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary) and not [android.preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary) which was deprecated in API 29.

**Solution Steps**

1. Create a custom layout
2. Create a new custom preference class by extending `Preference` class
3. Add an entry of this new class in your `preference.xml` file
4. Use this class in your `SettingsFragment`

**1 - Custom Layout**

Here is a simple custom layout that contains our `ImageView`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Syed Ahmed Jamil"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**2 - Create a new custom preference class by extending `Preference` class**

We are overriding the `onBindViewHolder()` method because this is where we are given a reference to our custom layout view from which we extract our `ImageView`.

Although you can provide a click listener to the `ImageView` directly inside `onBindViewHolder()` at this moment but providing this click listener in your `SettingsFragment` makes more sense. That is why we have created `setImageClickListener()` method.

we will use `setImageClickListener()` in step 4.

```
public class ImageViewPreference extends Preference {

    private ImageView imageView;
    View.OnClickListener imageClickListener;

    public ImageViewPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    //onBindViewHolder() will be called after we call setImageClickListener() from SettingsFragment
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        imageView = (ImageView)holder.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(imageClickListener);
    }

    public void setImageClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener)
    {
        imageClickListener = onClickListener;
    }
}
```

**3 - Add an entry of this new class in your `preference.xml` file**

Now add this new class to your `preference.xml` and set its layout using the `app:layout` attribute.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.example.preferencefragmentsample.ImageViewPreference
        app:key="image_preference"
        app:layout="@layout/custom_layout" />

    <Preference
        app:key="notifications"
        app:title="Notifications"
        app:summary="Enable or disable notifications"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_24dp"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
        />

    <Preference
        app:key="feedback"
        app:summary="Get to know the developer"
        app:title="About"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_24dp"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**4 - Use this class in your `SettingsFragment`**

Now just get a reference to `ImageViewPreference` using `findPreference()` by passing it the key string value that you defined in `preference.xml`.

After that just call the `setImageClickListener()` and provide it whatever functionality you want on click. As an example I'm just toasting a message showing *"Image Clicked"*

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    ImageViewPreference imageViewPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs,rootKey);

        imageViewPreference = (ImageViewPreference) findPreference("image_preference");

        if (imageViewPreference != null)
            imageViewPreference.setImageClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //do whatever you want on image click here
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


    }
}
```

**Final Output**

[image]

**UPDATE : Loading image from Firebase cloud storage**

> ***NOTE:*** I haven't had the time to actually test and run this. This is just to give you a flow of how to do it. But I have carefully
>   checked and everything seems fine and it should run as expected. I'll
>   leave some minor changes to you if there are some errors regarding
>   firebase or converting from File to Bitmap.

First modify `ImageViewPreference` class so it can receive and apply the bitmap to the `ImageView`. It is similar to as we received and applied the `onClickListener` to the `ImageView`.

```
public class ImageViewPreference extends Preference {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap imageBitmap;
    View.OnClickListener imageClickListener;

    public ImageViewPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    //onBindViewHolder() will be called after we call setImageClickListener() and setBitmap() from SettingsFragment
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder);
        imageView = (ImageView)holder.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(imageClickListener);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }

    public void setImageClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener)
    {
        imageClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        imageBitmap = bitmap;
    }
}
```

Now assuming you have already configured firebase cloud storage by following the docs. Retrieve the image in a local `File` object from firebase cloud storage using `getFile()` method and convert that file object to bitmap. After that just send that bitmap to `ImageViewPreference` using the `setBitmap()` method we created earlier.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    private Bitmap imageBitmap;
    ImageViewPreference imageViewPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs,rootKey);

        //Get your image in a local file and convert it into bitmap
        StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/yourImage.jpg");
        File localFile = File.createTempFile("myImage", "bmp");

        storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //Convert File to Bitmap
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });

        imageViewPreference = (ImageViewPreference) findPreference("image_preference");

        if (imageViewPreference != null)
        {
            imageViewPreference.setImageClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //do whatever you want on image click here
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            //Send the downloaded bitmap to ImageViewPreference
            imageViewPreference.setBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: That's great job, clean solution. I implemented it in kotlin. :-)

Comment: Can I load the image dynamically? from a backend by example

Comment: yes sure why not. either load the image from internet or database directly inside `onBindViewHolder` or the constructor of `ImageViewPreference`  and assign it in `onBindViewHolder` or you can load the image in `SettingsFragment` and assign it to `imageView` just like i assigned a `onClickListener`

Comment: How to do that in SettingFragment? It seem cleaner there

Comment: There are many ways. It depends also on what is your backend. Where are you loading your image data from ?

Comment: As a start whatever your backend is just use that backend to load image data into a `Bitmap` object in `SettingsFragment`. Then pass that `Bitmap` object to `ImageViewPreference` object and set the `ImageView` to that bitmap using `imageView.setImageBitmap()` inside `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: I'm loading from firebase

Comment: can you provide coe example please?

Comment: sorry for the late response. Unfortunately I am actually a bit busy. You can see the code example in the **UPDATE** section at the end that I posted just now. Hope it gives you an idea of how to do it.

Comment: how do you get the text color of the title preference to be black. that sample shows it as gray